# CSS: How to make text italic between img and br tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is something I have been struggling with for the last weeks now.

Let's say I have the following html (simplified example code)

```
<img class="myimageclass" /> This is some text <br />
```

Then my problem is: How could I make the text between the img en br tags italic? The text before the img tag and after the br should not be given the italic style though. This piece of code is found multiple times in the document.

Now this might seem like a very simple question but the thing is: I cannot make changes to the actual html. So the styling needs to be done with pure CSS or jQuery.

Does anybody know if this is possible? And if so, how?

I was personally thinking about using the :after and :before pseudo elements to insert tags. But I don't know if this is possible or if it would be the best way.

tnx!

Comment: I dont think if its possible with pure css.

Comment: `<img class="myimageclass" /> <i>This is some text</i> <br />` or `<img class="myimageclass" /> <em>This is some text</em> <br />` or `body { font-style: italic }`

Comment: Isn't there a parent element that you can target?

Comment: Why the downvote? You think I haven't put effort in this? I have been struggling with this for weeks. Just scaled it down to the very problem. Don't downvote because the question is too difficult.

Comment: It's not possible with pure CSS. If you can't change the HTML and you can't use JavaScript you're out of luck.

Comment: Yeah I am starting to believe that too, that jQuery is required. Well, that is an option although not ideal in this specific case.

Comment: "You think I haven't put effort in this?" We can't know. If you say you've struggled for weeks, surely you must have tried something - you'll have to show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

After much research and checking all the suggestions I think the only valid conclusion is that it is simply impossible to do so. jQuery is the only alternative in this case.

Thanks all for the suggestions!

Comment: If you are answering your own question, please answer it. In its current form, this is not an answer. Please post the jQuery solution, or delete the question altogether.

Comment: Since I am so bored with all the useless spamming I would really love to delete it, but I cannot delete it anymore.

Comment: Flag it, and ask moderators to delete it.

Answer (score -2):

```
<img class="myimageclass" /><span><i> This is some text</i></span> <br />
```

else the link below might helpful to u to learn before and after clause

http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3

Comment: "I cannot make changes to the actual html."

Answer (score -2):

The problem here is that you can't target/style plain text which is not within a tag.

So I think the best you can do here is set `font-style: italic;` on the body, and then assuming the rest of the text sits within tags like `<div>` or `<p>` - override that style to `font-style: normal;`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/32Esg)**

```
body
{
    font-style: italic;
}
p, div, span, input /* etc */
{
    font-style: normal;
}
```

If you had a parent element then you could target that

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/32Esg/1/)**

Comment: this will make whole HTML italic

Comment: yes I know that! - but being that there's no other html - I think that's ok

Comment: my friend he said `How could I make the text between the img en br tags italic` it means something else also exist on his page

Comment: Well, actually that's not what it means - it just means that there is text between the img and br tags - it doesn't mention any other elements on the page. If there *were* other elements - then you could style the parent element with italic - as I mentioned. .... In any case I updated my answer with overrides for other elements

Answer (score -2):

```
Please use this code it will work fine through the entire html following logic!
<!DOCTYpE html>
<html lang = "en"> 
<head>
    <title>Combinator</title>
 <style> 
   .myimageclass ~ p::first-line{
     color:hsla(0,100%,50%,1);
     font-style:italic;

 }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<img class="myimageclass" /> <p>This is some text </p><br />This is some textThis is some text
<img class="myimageclass" /> <p>This is some text</p><br />This is some textThis is some text
<img class="myimageclass" /> <p>This is some text</p><br />This is some textThis is some text
<img class="myimageclass" /> <p>This is some text</p><br />This is some textThis is some text
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: "I cannot make changes to the actual html."

Comment: Nice use of CSS. This answer does not deserve negative scores, even though it does not solve the problem 100%.

Comment: @AlexPakka Actually I think this is just silly -- if the OP could modify the HTML they could just wrap what they want to style into `<span>` and style it without complex CSS rules. (Besides it doesn't even do what the OP asks for: they want to style everything between the img and the br, not the first line between the img and the br.)

Comment: @Juhana: I agree the answer does not fit the question requirements and will not solve the problem. I also think that in "pure" form it is not solvable and we need to see more of the page infrastructure to approach it. So, author of the question deserves the minuses. This answer, however, provides an interesting approach and shows effort and someone might use it to create a better answer or use in the future when browsing SO. I see no reason to punish the author for this answer. Just my point of view, I might be wrong.

Answer (score -3):

Try the code below:

CSS Code:

```
img.myimageclass span{
font-style:italic;
}
```

jQuery Code:

```
$('.myimageclass>img').each(
   function(){
        $(this.firstChild).wrap('<span></span>');
    });
```

Without any changes in HTML Code.

Comment: jQuery is not CSS. CSS is CSS.

Comment: I'm not the asker. You might want to pay closer attention while you're here.

Comment: It's happened simultaneously! No pb about that.

Comment: `$(this.firstChild)` will not work because text is not child of image tag, you can see `img` tag is closed

Comment: jQuery is an option. Wrap method is a nice thought although indeed the selector wouldn't be correct.

Comment: Thinking of it and reading the answers here, I'm starting to believe that jquery might be the only option.